# issues with whereRaw in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to add this condition in my query.

```
$query = Cheques::select('id', 'deposit_date', 'number');
$query->where('product_cheques.cheque_status', Cheques::VERIFIED);

$query->whereRaw('DATE(product_cheques.deposit_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?', [$this->getTodayDate()->format('Y-m-d'), $this->addSevenDayBucket()->format('Y-m-d')]);

$query->get()->toArray();
```

I don't get any output when I run this. However, when I run the same query that ORM has executed

```
DATE(product_cheques.deposit_date) BETWEEN ? AND ?
[0] - 2016-02-01
[1] - 2016-02-15
```

with adding quotes to date field, I get the desired result.

```
where DATE(product_cheques.deposit_date) BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-15'
```

How can I modify my Eloquent query?

Comment: Can you show the whole query? You might not even need `whereRaw`.

Comment: Added the whole query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `whereRaw` for this query:

**Add to top of your controller:**

`use Carbon\Carbon;`

**And in your function:**

```
Cheques::select('id', 'deposit_date', 'number')
    ->where('cheque_status', Cheques::VERIFIED)
    ->whereDate('deposit_date', '>', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
    ->whereDate('deposit_date', '<', Carbon::today()->addWeeks(2)->toDateString())
    ->get();
```

See https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereDate and http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/.

Comment: What column type does the `deposit_date` column have in the database?

Comment: deposit_date is datetime in database.

Comment: Thanks this works. There was some error in returning the function.